# Restore mysql dump file with text field with single quotes in it

Tags: mysql, database, restore, dump, quote

I have a mysql dump file with tables which have text fields with single quotes (') not escaped ('') so when I try to restore the database I get syntax errors.

What can I do?

Thanks.

Comment: Open the NotePad++ and use the find and replace tool.Then find using `(')` and Replace it with `("'")`

Comment: How did you create that dump file? `mysqldump` already escapes quote characters properly.

Comment: I have the same problem. `mysqldump` did not escape the quotes inside the text values (I used `mysqldump --compatible=mssql`. Also, the suggestion in the answer won't work, because the text values are enclosed with quotes. any idea how a proper data dump into `INSERT` statements can be done?

Answer (score 1):

mysqldump by default will escape the quotes.
In my case it was an encoding issue that was causing the syntax errors.
I solved it by exporting the DB using this way:

```
mysqldump -u root -ppassword --default-character-set=utf8 --result-file=backup.sql database_name
```

and importing it back, using this way:

```
mysql -uroot -ppassword database_name --default_character_set utf8 < backup.sql
```